# Change hyperlink parameter value dynamically

Tags: php, jquery

Please advise on how to do this.

I have a html page with two different links like below

```
1)  http://domainONE.com/?a=100&b=$bvalue (this url is around in 45 places)
2)  http://domainTWO.com/?a=200&b=$bvalue (this url is around in 30 places)
```

Now I would like dynamically change (prefer PHP based solution) to assign b=  value(like link1, link2 link3…link45)  for domainONE.com and then  b=  number (like link46, link47 link48…link75). Looking to assign the b=$bvalue using a loop or other ways based on domain name so I don’t have to hardcode by finding each url on the page with link1 till link75)

I can explain more if it’s not clear. I am trying not to use jquery based solution thinking if that takes time to manipulate.

Regards

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Can you show more code around this? Like the page where the links are currently being output.

Comment: hi, i don't have a page yet but planning to have two variables $url1 = http://domainONE.com/?a=100&b=$bvalue & $url2 = http://domainTWO.com/?a=100&b=$bvalue. then on the page for all hyperlinks I am going to call echo $url1 and echo $url2 accordingly. As i want to track it easily, i want to keep the b value with different string for each url so i can track. sorry, no code as its on idea level if i can even do this

Answer (score 2):

Something like this with a switch:

```
switch($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
    case 'www.domain1.com':
        $bvalue = 100;
        break;

    case 'www.domain2.com':
        $bvalue = 200;
        break;
}
```

Or something with an array:

```
$domains = array('www.domain1.com' => array('bvalue' => 100),
                 'www.domain2.com' => array('bvalue' => 200),
);

$current = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$bvalue = $domains[$current]['bvalue'];
```

Depending on your requirements you might look through `$_SERVER` specifically `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` for something else or you may need to manipulate it somewhat to get the string that you want.